# Rails ActionMailer interceptor on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

I try to register some `ActionMailer` interceptors in my Rails app. 
For example, in my `/config/initializers/mailer.rb`

```
if Rails.env.staging?
  class PrefixStagingMailSubject
    def self.delivering_email(mail)
      mail.subject = "TEST #{mail.subject}"
    end
  end
  ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(PrefixStagingMailSubject)
end
```

This works fine on my developer machine. But it does not on Heroku server.

Occasionally I've figured out that it works in mails sent by Devise (e.g. reset password mail). That means that interceptor though have been registered.

But in my mailers it still doesn't work. For example my `ReportsMailer`

```
class ReportsMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def report_email(email, title, public_url)
    subject = "The #{title} report you've requested was generated"
    body = <<-EOS
      The #{title} report you've requested was generated
      You can download it by clicking the link below:

      ------------
      #{public_url}
    EOS

    mail(to: email, subject: subject, body: body)
  end
end
```

What could be the wrong?

Could someone please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you check the RAILS_ENV environment variable for your application? It should be `staging`, not `production`.

Comment: @eugen that was my thought at the beginning too. But reset password mail came with TEST in subject. It means that `RAILS_ENV = staging` and even interceptor registered correctly.

Comment: That's indeed strange, if it works for one mailer I can't see why it doesn't work for all. I have a similar interceptor that works, the only difference is that I register it with `Mail.register_interceptor` instead of `ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor`, and I register it before setting up the rest of the `ActionMailer::Base.smtp` settings. I doubt that would make a difference, though.

Comment: @eugen I agree with you it's very strange) Thank you for advice. I've thought about importance of loading order, but again all work properly in development. I'll try to use `Mail` instead of `ActionMailer::Base` and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I feel very stupid.
Message sendings are processed by Sidekiq.
But I totally forgot that Sidekiq has its own `ENV`.
I have `config/initializers/mailer.rb` with the following code

```
if Rails.env.staging?
  class PrefixStagingMailSubject
    def self.delivering_email(mail)
      mail.subject = "TEST #{mail.subject}"
    end
  end
  ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(PrefixStagingMailSubject)
end
```

So I believe the problem was that Sidekiq was running without specifying
`ENV` and have some default `ENV` (maybe development).

I updated my Procfile file like

```
web: ...
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e $SIDEKIQ_ENV ...
```

and set `SIDEKIQ_ENV = staging` in Heroku config.

Now evething seems working fine.